# How to pass variable to .SelectMany

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Feeling like a total dunce here. I have a parent object that holds collections of child objects for each day of the week. So I can do something like `parent.MondayChildren` or `parent.TuesdayChildren` etc.

I have a collection of parent objects and in my linq query I want to use `parents.SelectMany(c => c.MondayChildren)` but based on the current day of the week.

How can I provide a variable to the `SelectMany` method?

UPDATED INFO:

I see now that I have missed vital info out. This query is going to get converted to SQL. To explain, Units are made up of multiple SlotPools and PatientSchedules are assigned to a slotpool for each day of the week.

My code is below which causes an Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.

```
Func<SlotPool, IEnumerable<PatientSchedule>> queryDay = null;

            switch (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                    queryDay = d => d.MondayPatientSchedules;
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                    queryDay = d => d.TuesdayPatientSchedules;
                    break;
                // .. Not shown for brevity
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported DayOfWeek");
            }    

IEnumerable<UnitWithCountVM> data = _unitOfWork.Units.GetAll()
                .Select(u => new UnitWithCountVM()
                {
                    ID = u.ID,
                    Name = u.Name,
                    PatientNumber = u.SlotPools.SelectMany(queryDay).Count()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: No special syntax is needed for that. Please show the actual code you have problem with and describe what works unlike you expect it to work.

Comment: Can you add a code example of what you expect? You can't pass a variable to `SelectMany`, but you can include local variables in the closure of the `Func` passed to `SelectMany`...

Comment: If you are using EntityFramework you need to be working with `Expression<Func<SlotPool, IEnumerable<PatientSchedule>>>` also some of your `IEnumerable`s should likely be `IQueryable`s

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain your comment gave me enough of a push to hit upon the right answer. Answer posted in the question.

Comment: @Copers post the answer as an answer. You can accept your own answer after you wait two days.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with a `switch`:

```
List<Children> todaysChildren = parents
    .SelectMany(p =>
    {
        switch(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                return p.MondayChildren; 
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                return p.TuesdayChildren; 
            // ...
            default: 
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported DayOfWeek");
        }
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but I couldn't use this solution as the query needs to get converted to SQL. I had missed this out and have now updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution. The key was to provide an Expression but also to add .AsQueryable() to my SlotPools collection. If anyone sees a problem I might have missed then please let me know. I am very new to EntityFramework and Linq:

```
Expression<Func<SlotPool, IEnumerable<PatientSchedule>>> queryDay = null;


        switch (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                queryDay = d => d.MondayPatientSchedules;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                queryDay = d => d.MondayPatientSchedules;
                break;
            // .. Not shown for brevity
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported DayOfWeek");
        }

        IEnumerable<UnitWithCountVM> data = _unitOfWork.Units.GetAll()
            .OrderBy(u => u.Name)
            .Select(u => new UnitWithCountVM()
            {
                ID = u.ID,
                Name = u.Name,
                PatientNumber = u.SlotPools.AsQueryable().SelectMany(queryDay).Count()
            }).ToList();
```